# Any way to create a VimL equivalent of Python's @property decorator?

Tags: vimscript, functions

As the title says, I'd like to be able to use something like Python's `@property` decorator (its semantics ofc, not the syntax) when writing a 'class' in VimL.

Currently I have something along the following the lines:

```
let s:File = {}

let s:File.curr_filename = function('s:get_curr_filename')
let s:File.curr_file_dir = function('s:get_curr_file_dir')
```

(the two above `get` functions can be assumed to work correctly)

Now if I want to get the value of `curr_filename` and `curr_file_dir` of the `s:File` object, I'd have to invoke them as functions, which is awkward. So if possible, I'd like these members to appear as properties, but behave as methods which evaluate to the correct value dynamically whenever accessed; this is basically what Python's `property` decorator provides.

Can this be (easily) achieved in VimL?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is impossible. Since I'm not 100% sure and can't "cite" anything, I'll refrain from answering. But I would suggest you don't keep your hopes up. :) (If I'm wrong, then I will be glad to see it!)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't see how as Vim provides no way to override the behaviour of assignment or of coercion (C++ way) or the "equivalent" we have in Python behind `property`.

At best we can define a `:PropSet`  command that forwards the assignment through the setter. But I don't see any simple way to handle situations where we need to evaluate expressions as this would require to parse manually a complex expression where sometimes the dot would mean access to the property or the method or concatenate.

(Dare I say it's better to use object programing to model behaviours and not data aggregation: https://www.infoworld.com/article/2073723/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html By thinking about what my objects can do for me and not what they can remember I hardly need setters/getters/properties even in VimL.)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the insight.